# React class component issue in order of execution

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-class-based-component

I have the following code in my React class component.

For some reason, I am observing that, inside `componentDidMount`, despite having the keyword `await` before the call to `this.getKeyForNextRequest()`, the execution is jumping to the next call, `this.loadGrids()`.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getKeyForNextRequest();
    await this.loadGrids();
}

getKeyForNextRequest = async () => {
    const dataRequester = new DataRequester({
      dataSource: `${URL}`,
      requestType: "POST",
      params: {
      },
      successCallback: response => {
        console.log(response);
      }
});

dataRequester.requestData();
}
loadGrids = async () => {
    await this.loadGrid1ColumnDefs();
    this.loadGrid1Data();
    await this.loadGrid2ColumnDefs();
    this.loadGrid2Data();
}
```

Comment: You are not returning a promise from getKeyForNextRequest method

Comment: Wouldn't you need to return a promise that resolves to `response` in `successCallback`? `getKeyForNextRequest` returns a promise, but it's one that resolves instantly to `undefined` rather than having anything to do with `successCallback`...

Comment: `getKeyForNextRequest` doesn't return a value so the function immediately resolves. There is nothing to wait for.

Comment: @DrewReese - Thanks...What do I need to add inside getKeyForNextRequest ? Basically, I set a state/key inside the "successCallback" of getKeyForNextRequest and that is to be used in the next AJAX calls (i.e. for loadGrid1Data)

Comment: Dunno, depends on what you are trying to wait for I guess. Maybe `return dataRequester` and/or (or both) return a Promise and add a call to resolve to the `successCallback` function? UPDATE: See @ggorlen's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `Promise` constructor:

```
getKeyForNextRequest = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const dataRequester = new DataRequester({
      dataSource: `${URL}`,
      requestType: "POST",
      params: {},
      successCallback: response => {
        console.log(response);
        resolve(response);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

This ensures you're waiting for a relevant promise, one that resolves only upon `successCallback` completing, rather than one that resolves instantly to `undefined` as you have it currently.

This is called ["promisifying" the callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises).

If `DataRequester` offers a promise-based mode, use that instead of promisifying the callback.